# cakephp email as HTML Email

Tags: html, email, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 1.2's default smtp email component, which sends email as text, while i would like to send as HTML, any idea how can i?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the cookbook in setting up the layouts.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1287/Setting-up-the-Layouts

Basically you need to set up the HTML views and then use them instead of just sending a text mail

There is also a tutorial on how to do this : http://lecterror.com/articles/view/using-emailcomponent-in-cakephp-1-2

Also, consider upgrading your CakePHP version.